# One face on the UV map is upside down

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, texture-baking, baking

I have a simple Chimney model, but when I bake AO it looks like one of the faces is upside down:

[image]

Shy is it happening and how can it be fixed?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Recalculating normal for that face?

Answer (score 1):

I would try highlighting it in the UV image editor, (if you cant isolate it in the UV window highlight it in the 3d view port and it will show in the UV window next to it,) then rotate that particular part of the UV map. If this doesn't work try a new UV unwrap with smart UV project.

Comment: To make this work select the face in the 3d viewport, then in the UV editor press: S Y -1 (negative 1) to flip the texture vertically.